# CSS3 Image flip Animation issues in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm building a personal website and in the header section(i.e div) i've a logo for which i'm trying to add flip animation on hover, to show the content written back of the logo. Need a help in fixing the problem with browser Chrome as well as IE11. Works fine with Mozilla.

```
<div id="logo">
<div id="logo_card" class="shadow">
    <div class="front face">
        <img src="./images/logo+.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="back face center">
        <p>Sooner the logo will be changed</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS for animation:

```
#logo{
width:450px;
height:150px;
margin-left:300px;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 1;
}

#logo {
  perspective: 1000;
}

#logo_card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#logo:hover #logo_card {
    -moz-transform: rotatey(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotatey(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotatey(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(180deg);
    transform: rotatey(180deg);
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.face.back {
    display: block;
    -moz-transform: rotatey(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotatey(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotatey(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(180deg);
    transform: rotatey(180deg);
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*padding: 10px;*/
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,arial,sans-serif;

}
```

Greately this works fine with Mozilla firefox browser only :(

Thank you,

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome 35 and IE 11 [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrAaN).

Comment: First of all Thank you jsFiddle i was stuck in image gallery issue but your comment to someone reg the same issue solved my problem. Well for me in chrome the content appears on the image and even after i hover on the logo div the image is still visible in reverse. While in IE11 its the same case :(